# Nested table row <tr> cannot appear as a child of <tr>. React

Tags: html, reactjs

Im trying to display a nested row in my table, but keep getting a "validateDOMNesting(...): tr> cannot appear as a child of tr>." warning

I tried creating a separate component and passing the data like so:

```
function TableRow({ order, index, handleDeletePurchaseOrders }) {
 return (
     <tr key={index} style={{ fontSize: "0.9rem" }}>
       <td>{order.code}</td>
       <td>{order.customer.split("- ")[1]}</td>

       {order.orderProducts.map((product, i) => (
         <tr key={i}>
           <td>{product.productName}</td>
         </tr>
       ))}
       <td>{new Date(order.purchaseDate).toLocaleDateString()}</td>
       <td>
         {order.paymentDate === null
           ? "Pendiente"
           : new Date(order.paymentDate).toLocaleDateString()}
       </td>
       <td>{order.shippingMode}</td>
       <td>{order.shippingAddress}</td>
       <td>{order.shippingState}</td>
       <td>{order.saleMode}</td>
       <td>{order.payMethod}</td>
       <td>{order.paymentState}</td>

       <td>{order.orderNotes}</td>
       <td className="actions-td">
         <div
           className="actionsIcon-wrapper"
           onClick={() => handleDeletePurchaseOrders(order._id)}
         >
           <FiTrash size={20} />
         </div>
       </td>
     </tr>

export default TableRow;
```

I tried adding tbody/table/fragments as stated in other solutions but keep getting this warning and im sure something is wrong because the cell is also looking funny.

This is the parent component:

```
 <table className="table table-responsive">
            <thead>
              <tr style={{ fontSize: "1rem", whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Productos</th>
                <th>Fecha de compra</th>
                <th>Fecha de pago</th>
                <th>Modo de entrega</th>
                <th>Dirección de entrega</th>
                <th>Estado de entrega</th>
                <th>Modo de venta</th>
                <th>Forma de pago</th>
                <th>Estado de pago</th>
                <th>Notas</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {purchaseOrdersData.map((order, index) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={index}
                  order={order}
                  handleDeletePurchaseOrders={handleDeletePurchaseOrders}
                />
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: "Im trying to display a nested row in my table" — That doesn't make sense. Which is why it isn't allowed. Which is why React is complaining at you. So stop trying to do that and step back to look at [your actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. Ive found like 12 results with the same problems, its just the solutions they offer do not work. Did you read the post at least?

Comment: You can not put a `<tr>` as a child element of another `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML specification does not allow `<tr>` elements to be nested inside other `<tr>` elements on their own. You'll need to wrap the nested `<tr>` elements in their own table. The [Table Row element technical summary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#technical_summary) (particularly the "Permitted parents" section) may provide some additional context.

Edit: The minimum allowable scenario for nested tables would look something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. Ive tried wrapping it with table and tbody but i keep getting similar messages, like: <table> cannot appear as a child of <tr>.
I understand the HTML table structure, im doing it as i should (Table>tbody>tr>td).
Maybe there is other way of doing this? Im just triyng to print a column with a few products for the same customer. Ty!!

Comment: Yeah, the table structure when they're nested is a little confusing. The trick with nesting tables is that each table needs to be complete (so you can only really insert a nested table inside a `<td>` element). The MDN documentation on [nesting tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Advanced#nesting_tables) provides some additional info.

Comment: I've created a [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/jedeen/pen/LYewmWP) of a more detailed example.


Since nesting tables is generally not recommended, you might try using a comma-separated list in a single table cell to list the multiple products.

Comment: I see now, ty so much for your help man.